Liquibase DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK.LOCKED column data type
After trying to migrate my database from Oracle to Postgres Liquibase has problems setting the lock because the LOCKED column got converted from NUMBER(1) to int4 and the update statement is using boolean which works in Oracle but not in Postgres:
UPDATE databasechangeloglock SET LOCKED = TRUE, LOCKEDBY = '<<<machine name>>>', LOCKGRANTED = '2024-11-01 17:17:38.911' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = FALSE 

which results in the following error:
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = boolean

My question is whether the only solution would be to convert the LOCKED column in Postgres to boolean or can the statement be configured in Liquibase?

You need to manually convert that, Liquibase won't fix it for you.
